# No reference even from coworker

Tags: references

I apologize in advance for the length of my dilemma.

I was recently fired from my last position as an Office Administrator at a small physio clinic and will not be receiving a reference letter and in fact may even receive a negative review if my employers were called.  There were two partners and one of them was fairly new and did not like me very much but as my work performance was excellent and there were never any complaints from my bosses or patients, we seemed to get along.

But there were some working conditions regarding cancellation of benefits, cancelling laundry service which suddenly becoming my responsibility to wash, dry and fold blankets, sheets, mountains of towels and gowns, on top of all the other duties and A/R billing I had, no lunch breaks given during a 10 hour day, directing me to bill insurance and lawyers even if the patient didn't show,(I did not follow that directive by the way as I knew the potential for trouble for me down the line) and constant unwanted oversharing of intimate details of the partner's divorce and marital woes, with no compensation for the extra work and cancelled benefits.    My frustration led me to vent; without mentioning any names of the people involved or the name of where I worked (and in fact only one person knew the name of the place I worked) to some people who I did not work with and was basically seeking advice from.

I had become terribly unhappy up with a job I had once loved, began looking for other work and started receiving interview requests.  I gave myself a time frame that if I had sufficient interest coming in I would quit regardless and make finding a good place to work my full time job.   Well it appears someone got back to my employer and I don't know exactly what was said or how it was delivered but the upshot was that my employer felt that I was being disloyal and trying to damage the reputation of the company and they fired me several days before I was planning to give notice!!  If it had been my intention to damage my employer in any way, I could have taken my concerns to an entirely different set of folks.

I got along extremely well with my co worker and she at one point asked me to give her a personal reference because the partner had given a negative one for a volunteer position she was applying for.  I asked my co worker to do the same and she went to the boss and they expressly forbid her to do it.  She apologized but said was fearful of repercussions if she did as I asked.

Sorry for this being so long, but my question is this:

I have two previous employers who I have contacted and will give me glowing references, but it's going to be hard to explain why I was fired so suddenly from my most recent job after 3 years of being an excellent employee.  I don't want to trash or cast aspersions on my former employer in any way in an interview, but who would believe me without an explanation, and how would I go about it as I have several scheduled?  I contacted my former employer and apologized and asked how they would respond to a potential employer but they did not reply.  A former co worker has been asked to step in and do coverage until they find someone else, so I can't ask her since she's technically working for them although I feel sure that she would have otherwise. I'm sure that by now she has been told not to as well.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? I don't see anything here that we can really help you with... Try asking another co-worker, if you haven't scared them all off?

Comment: Coworkers were told not to.  They all saw what happened to me.  They have all most likely been told by now not to do it.   My question is:  I have two previous employers who I have contacted and will give me glowing references, but its going to be hard to explain why I was fired so suddenly from my most recent job after 3 years of being an excellent employee.  I don't want to cast aspersions on my former employer in any way in an interview as that would be doing what they have claimed that I did, how would I go about it as I have several scheduled?  I am in need good sound advice.

Comment: I just got a reply to an email I sent to my former boss, (not the partner) and where I asked him what he might be prepared to say if contacted by a prospective employer and he wrote back:

"Hi If I am approached by a future employer I will rill in any form as best I can for you.  Thanks, Joe.  I know that`s very non-committal, but not terrible right?